# My app does not support Portrait mode but at times it turning into portrait mode

Tags: orientation, screen-orientation, uiinterfaceorientation, device-orientation, orientation-changes

My app does not support Portrait mode but at times it turning into portrait mode. I am using Xcode 5.02 & I am running my app on iOS7. I unchecked the portrait mode in the settings so that it does not support portrait, but at a point of time it is turning into portrait, I dont have any clue, any one to help me out, my app is master-detail base. This below code snippet in app delegate & dashboardNavController is UINavigationController

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.dashboardNavController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

if  needed I am glad to provide more informations, Thanks in  advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this in ViewDidLoad

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI/2);
self.view.transform = transform;

// Repositions and resizes the view.
// If you need NavigationBar on top then set height appropriately 
CGRect contentRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.size.height, self.view.size.width);
self.view.bounds = contentRect;
```